# CSS background color will not apply

Tags: php, css, html

I am completely stumped. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
<style>

body {
background-color: rgba(75,157,215,1);}

</style>
```

And here is the entirety of the code from the index file:

```
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/nav.php"); ?>


<img src="images/page.jpg"/>


<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

The body tags are included in the header and footer.php pages, and everything else in the css works. The background remains white, and I have tried everything. Sorry If this is overly obvious.

Comment: Why do you have `<body>` tags inside the "header.php" and "footer.php" pages? That tag is unique, and the page should only have one set of those.

Comment: Your browser may not support rgba alpha channels. Change it to rgb(75,157,215). Also, shouldn't make a difference but put the whole CSS statement on one line. Worked for me once. Also, the link tag for the stylesheet should be in the HEAD section, clearly defined as such rather than just outside the body.

Answer (score 0):

If your styles.css file does include the style tags remove them. If they are used the css declarations are ignored.

This could also be a browser issue since older ones do not support the alpha channel.

Comment: This is a comment. (i did not down)

Comment: no it's the answer. If he is indeed wrapping his css file declarations in <style> tags then they won't work.

Comment: If it's an answer, why does it contain 2 questions?

Comment: very true, updated my answer removing the questions. Keeping the intent of the content the same.